# Clickable Button outside parent view

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have got button attached to view with this frame:

### CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 80, -35, 60, 60)

The part of button that is outside main view is not clickable...

Is any solution to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your main view you should add this:

```
 - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      if (CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, point)) {
           return button;
      }
      return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Outside bound of `UIView` will not be `clickable`  by any means.

One option can be add `UIButton` to `UIWindow`like this :

```
//Calculate frame according to screen use it in button's frame
//Intializa button and add target to it
[self.view.window addSubView:yourButtonHere]
```